# How to see which routes are being accessed with Flask gunicorn?

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn, amazon-cloudwatch

My flask api shows which routes are being accessed in the dev environment. But when running behind gunicorn in production, all route access info is suppressed.

On heroku, I can still see route access info with the `heroku logs --tail` command, but I just moved to EC2 and I am lost on where I might be able to get this info.

Is this something that I need to configure CloudWatch to be able to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to launch gunicorn with [accesslog](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logging) enabled.

To log to `stdout`, similar to the flask dev server (with those log entries visible in the console):

```
--access-logfile -
```

Or if you want to send the log entries to a file, provide a filename:

```
--access-logfile FILE
```